# eJabberd connection to facebook xmpp

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

I am creating chat application that will connect to facebook chat via XMPP. I installed eJabberd server, and, I am looking for a way to to hook to messages that comes from the client in order to add the access token and the api key/secret to the message before I am sending it to facebook, and I can't figure out how to do it, is it via one of the pre defined ejabber modules, or I need to develop one?

** I can connect with pidgin to facebook xmpp using the eJabberd server I installed.

Thanks.

Comment: What kind of app is it? Web? Desktop? Android? Whatever your using you'll probably need to follow http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0077.html.

Comment: I suspect you have some development to do to get ejabberd to connect to Facebook.  ejabberd is a server, and as such would normally make s2s (server-to-server) connections to other servers, but Facebook Chat only supports c2s (client-to-server) connections.  It would probably be possible to write an ejabberd module that impersonates a Facebook user to the Facebook Chat server.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your response. I managed to overcome this with punjab and strophe.js. https://github.com/javierfigueroa/turedsocial